# Is there a way in tkinter to resize images with the mouse?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was just wondering, is there any way in tkinter in python to resize/rescale a picture with the mouse (similar to how you can rescale images in google docs)?
The code I have so far:

```
def addImage(self, docx):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(title="Select a file")
    myImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename.name))
    position = docx.index(INSERT)
    docx.image_create(position, image=myImage)
    docx.photo = myImage

    # here I want to be able to resize the image I have put in my document with the mouse
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible, yes, but difficult. Not for a beginner programmer. You would need to make a custom widget that displayed the handles and reacted to them.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

class Resizable:
    def __init__(self,label,image):
        self.label=label
        self.image=image
        self.label.master.bind('<Motion>',self.position)        
        self.flag=False 

    def position(self,event):
        self.dimentions=(self.label.winfo_width(),self.label.winfo_height())
        self.x,self.y = event.x,event.y
        if (
            self.x in range (self.dimentions[0]-5,self.dimentions[0],1) and 
            self.y in range (self.dimentions[1]-5,self.dimentions[1],1)
        ):
            self.label.config(cursor='sizing')
            self.label.master.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.end)
            self.label.bind('<Button-1>',self.start)
        else:
            self.label.config(cursor='')    
            self.label.unbind('<Button-1>')

    def end(self,event):
        self.flag=True
        self.label.master.unbind('<ButtonRelease-1>')

    def start(self,event):
        self.flag=False
        self.resize()

    def resize(self):
        if not self.flag:
            self.label.config(cursor='sizing')
            try:
                self.photoimage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize((self.x,self.y),Image.ANTIALIAS))
            except:
                pass
            self.label.config(image=self.photoimage)
            self.label.update()
            self.label.after(1,self.resize)

root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

img_label=Label(bd=0)
img_label.pack()
image=Image.open('sample.png')
photoimage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS))
img_label.config(image=photoimage)
Resizable(img_label,image)

root.mainloop()
```

I believe you have a different way of inserting your image, but you can modify and improve this approach as per your requirement.